# Encapsulate a method decorator - Typescript

Tags: typescript, discord.js, nestjs, decorator

So I’m fairly new to developing my own decorators for my application.
I am developing a discordjs bot using Nestjs as a backend and [Necord](https://necord.org) as a library to use decorators to register slash commands.

I'd like to modify the behavior of Necord’s method decorator `@SlashCommand` that lets you register a slash command for a discord bot. This command takes some parameters such as the name of the command. I'd like to modify this decorator to log information in the console each time a command is executed, but unfortunately I can't do it.

So I tried to create my own decorator using these lines of code:

```
import { SlashCommand } from 'necord';

// Log decorator
export function Log(name: any) {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        // Calls the SlashCommand decorator to register the command
        const originalMethod: any = SlashCommand(name)(target, propertyKey, descriptor);

        descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
            console.log('[SlashCommand] Calling slash command: ' + name);
            return originalMethod.apply(this, args);
        };
        // Return the method
        return descriptor;
    };
}
```

Either the command isn't properly logged to discord.js or it isn't logged at all, depending on what I try. I tried several variants of this decorator, like placing the call to SlashCommand decorator after the descriptor redefinition and returning it, but nothing works the way I want.

I want my decorator to work the same way as the original necord’s decorator with just adding a log to the console. I also want to use it to register commands that take parameters on discord.